# Moving a Django app into production using Nginx and Gunicorn, there are no errors but the page doesn't show

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to setup an app on my Digital Ocean production server, I've followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04), testing gunicorn and nginx,I could access the app in gunicorn and both services start fine with no errors logged. However when I go to the site it does not show anything. This is a subdomain of my main site. Mostly I'm looking to find a place to start troubleshooting this especially since everything looks fine.

**Configs:**

**Nginx config for subdomain (Django) site:**

```
server {
  # use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
  # use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
  listen 80;

  # set the correct host(s) for your site
  server_name subdomain.domain_name.com www.subdomain.domain_name.com;

  location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}
  location /static/ {
    root /path/to/static/files;
  }

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/.sock/file;
  }

}
```

**Nginx config for main (static) site:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/main_site_folder;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain_name www.domain_name;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Description of the app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=MyUserName
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app_directory/
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/and/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/app_dir/.sock_filename app_name.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an A record for the sub-domain , this was a classic case of not being able to find the answer because it was right in front of my face.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by changing `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` in `settings.py`. Also try accessing your URL through CURL.

Comment: Curl doesn't return anything for the subdomain but returns the HTML for the main domain.